# Why can a web app prefer one webserver over another?

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx, webserver

According to [these](http://typo3.org/typo3-cms/overview/requirements/) System requirements, then Typo3 recommends Apache over nginx. This am I surprised about, as I would have expected that all webservers have the same abstraction layer.

**Question**

How can an application prefer one (Linux) webserver over another?

Or is this just one of those cases, where the developers are using Apache them self, and therefore recommends it?

Comment: No, the application _may_ use server specific stuff like environment variables and extensions (modules) which may not be available for all http servers.

Comment: You're asking us to explain why another person thinks/believes what they do.... that's asking for opinions, and as such I'm voting to close the question

Comment: It appears to be suggesting that NginX is still supported, so it may be that Apache is just the most tested, which would not be surprising. You can always test Typo3 on NginX, and if it works for you, go for it! However bear in mind that Apache is probably more popular, so if you want community support, it may be the more practical choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All listed webservers are supported, so I guess by stating that one of them is "recommended" they intend to say that they have best experience with it or maybe also do more testing with this server (or as you write, they use mainly Apache themselves).

But it's hard to answer. You should ask them directly for what reason they recommend Apache. ;-)